# javascript get substring of string at n of the same char

Tags: javascript

I have the string:

```
"A1111A2222A3333A4444"
```

how do I get the string:

```
"A1111"
```

I need to be able to get it by specifying the number of 'A' chars from the end and removing this portion from the total string.

EDIT:

I have a large string separated by the char 'A', for example:

```
"A11A22A33A44A55A66A77A88A99"
```

What I need is a function that will give me the substring from 0 to the index of n 'A' chars away. For example, getSubstring(3) would return:

```
"A11A22A33A44A55A66"
```

Comment: `"A1111A2222A3333A4444".substring(0, 5)`? What do you mean "specifying the number of 'A' chars"?

Comment: I have a massive string separated by multiple 'A' chars. I need the substring from 0 to the index of the last N 'A' chars.

Comment: `"A1111A2222A3333A4444".split('A').slice(0, -n).join('A')`? Not sure if I understood correctly

Comment: Editted, hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. `split` the string using the character as the separator
2. Use `slice` to get a subarray with all items except the last `n` items
3. `join` back that subarray

```js
function getSubstring(str, ch, n) {
  return str.split(ch).slice(0, -n).join(ch);
}
getSubstring("A1111A2222A3333A4444", "A", 3); // "A1111"
getSubstring("A11A22A33A44A55A66A77A88A99", "A", 3); // "A11A22A33A44A55A66"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
var str = "A1111A2222A3333A4444";
var pattern = /A1*4/;
```

`search()` will tell you at what index the match was found

```
str.search(pattern)
```

`match()` will return 'A1111'.  (match accually returns an array with [0] being the string that was searched and [1] being the matched part of the string.

```
str.match(pattern)[1];
```